# If $|28 - x^2| < |3x|$ ,then what is the product of all possible integer values of $x$?

Tags: contest-math, absolute-value

$|28 - x^2| < |3x|$
$\Rightarrow |x^2-28| < |3x| $

Case $1$ when $3x \geq 0 \Rightarrow x \geq0$ :-
$|x^2-28| < 3x$
$\Rightarrow -3x < x^2-28 < 3x $
$\Rightarrow x \in (4,7) \Rightarrow x=5,6$

Case $1$ when $3x \lt 0 \Rightarrow x \lt 0$ :-
$|x^2-28| < -3x$
$\Rightarrow -3x < x^2-28 < 3x $
$\Rightarrow x \in ( -\infty ,-7)  \bigcup ( -4 ,0)  $

How do we find the integers in the second case? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: in the second case, my solutions are less than 0 only.

Comment: But there are finitely many. Besides there is an error. $$3x<x^2-28<-3x$$

Comment: The second inequality gives the interval $(-7,4)$  while the first one $x>7$ and $x<-4.$ Both  conditions  should be satisfied and $x\le 0.$ Thus you obtain $-6$ and $-5.$ Actually you do not need to consider the case $x\le 0.$ The inequality is symmetric. So $n$ is a solution iff $-n$ is a solution.

Comment: Easy to miss that the LHS has $x^2$ and the RHS has $|x|$, which is why $(n)$ is a solution if and only if $(-n)$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error when you wrote
$$-3x<x^2-28<3x$$
Since you took $x<0$, $3x<-3x$; the correct inequality will be,
$$3x<x^2-28<-3x$$
which gives $-7<x<-4$, giving the integers $x=-5,-6$.

Nonetheless, as mentioned in the comments by @RyszardSzwarc, you do not need to consider separate cases because the inequality remains the same if you replace $x$ by $-x$, so you can just fix one sign for $x$, and the negatives of those will also be a solution. (In this case, $5$ and $6$ being solutions implies $-5$ and $-6$ also being solutions.)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Ok.. I totally missed that.Thanks for such a clear explanation.